# online learning for label encoder and random forest classifier

Tags: python, classification, random-forest, label-encoding, online-machine-learning

I have a very large dataset that needs to be used for classification, I sampled the data, but that does not guarantee that I will have the whole labels in my output. How can I sample my data to cover all labels?
Also, I wanted to save the `label encoder` and the `RandomForestClassifier` that I used in this process to use them for incremental learning. I searched about using the `RandomForestClassifier` I found out that `set_warm` feature is only used for adding extra estimators not updating the weights. and `partial_fit` does not support using random forest. So my second question is how to updated the `label encoder` and the `RandomForestClassifier` for training another datasets that might have other labels and more datapoints?

Comment: Why not subset the dataset first according to labels and then use sampling on it as it will also make sure your dataset is balanced

Comment: Thank you so much. that's a good point regarding my first question, but what if in the future I had a new data that has more labels? I would have to use incremental learning to combine between my current data and the other data labels